# Origin of the name of the seafood restaurant Melville's on Cheers

Tags: cheers

On the American television sit-com *Cheers* there was a seafood restaurant over the bar.  This restaurant was called Melville's.  Recently I have begun to suspect the restaurant was named after Herman Melville, the author of *Moby-Dick*.  Both Herman Melville and whaling did have a significant connection to Boston, the setting of the show.

Despite being a long-time fan of the show who has seen every episode multiple times I do not recall such a connection being mentioned on screen.  All I can find online is a Reddit post from 2018 in which someone suggests the same origin as I do here for the restaurant's name:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Cheers/comments/9slfxa/moby_dick_references/

Has such a connection ever been confirmed maybe by someone from the show during an interview?

**EDIT**

In addition to the *Moby-Dick* references at the Reddit post above Cliff actually says, 'Call me Ishmael' in the Season 6 episode *Our Hourly Bread*.

Comment: Seafood, yeah, would point predominantly towards Herman, but the Melville family name would carry prestigious local connotations beyond just him (eg Herman’s grandfather Thomas Melville) that I guess the script writers might have wanted to tap into.